# Three.js: chaotic mesh rotation after applyMatrix

Tags: matrix, three.js, transformation, mesh

After applying a matrix to mesh I print its rotation parameters.
After resetting mesh rotation, scale and position and re-applying the same matrix - rotation parameters aren't equal to previous ones.

```js
var ctm1 = new THREE.Matrix4();
var ctm2 = new THREE.Matrix4();
ctm1.set(...............);
ctm2.set(...............);

function reset(mesh)
{
  mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
  mesh.scale.set(5,5,5);
  mesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);
}

reset(myMesh);
myMesh.applyMatrix(ctm1);
console.log(myMesh.rotation.x);

reset(myMesh);
myMesh.applyMatrix(ctm2);

reset(myMesh);
myMesh.applyMatrix(ctm1);
console.log(myMesh.rotation.x); //Isn't equal to previous output !!!
```

Three.js r.58

Comment: Did you study the source code of `Object3D.applyMatrix()`?

Comment: No. It seems that I have to.

Comment: @WestLangley: so, what you are trying to say is that `m1` couldn't be reset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three.js renderer handles updating the object `matrix`, so that the matrix is consistent with the object's `position`, `rotation`, and `scale.`

Since you do not make a `render()` call, you need to add `mesh.updateMatrix()` as the last line of your `reset()` function.

three.js r.58