# Three.js: how to apply rotation matrix to some base object's state?

Tags: matrix, rotation, three.js, transformation

In this question

[Three.js: chaotic mesh rotation after applyMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221738/three-js-chaotic-mesh-rotation-after-applymatrix)

I asked about an issue.

Now I'll try to look at the issue from another end: to describe the desired behaviour of the program.

I have an array of rotation matrices for each time point of object's state.
Each rotation matrix represents a difference between some initial object state (point zero) and the desired state. User should be able at any time select any desired rotation matrix from the array.

How to implement the correct rotation for such data?

Three.js r.58

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three.js expects the user to set the object's `position`, `rotation`, and `scale`, and then the renderer updates the object `matrix` in the `render()` function.

Usually it is unadvisable to manipulate the matrix directly, unless you really know what you are doing.

In any event, something like this should work.

```
object.matrix.copy( matrixIntiial );
object.applyMatrix( matrixDelta );
```

three.js r.58