# how do I rotate an object3d in threejs by directly manipulating the matrix elements?

Tags: graphics, 3d, three.js

to translate along z axis right now I am doing

```
object.matrix.elements[14] += (0.1);
object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
```

How do I turn this same object by 5 degrees clockwise around the z axis?

Comment: In three.js is it best not to manipulate the object matrix directly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240008/three-js-how-to-apply-rotation-matrix-to-some-base-objects-state/17240672#17240672

Comment: I wonder why would you want to do it - what is wrong with object's rotation property?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(5));
object.position.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix);
```